# Function not reloading data after fetching automatically

Tags: javascript

everyone. Hope everyone is safe. I have a question.
I'm building this email-like application with javascript as a project for CS50 Web.
Everything is working smoothly, but I have this "archive" button that should update the database, return to the "inbox" page and show the emails that are unarchived, and hide it otherwise.

However, after I click this archive button, it updates the database, returns to the inbox but it doesn't update the page. Once I refresh, it works.

I have a feeling this error has something to do with the fetch methods.
Can someone help me?
Any advice on how to improve my code would be highly appreciated as well.

```
function load_mailbox(mailbox) {

  // Show the mailbox and hide other views
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'flex';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#emails-page').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#emails-page').innerHTML = '';

  // Show the mailbox name
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').innerHTML = `<h3>${mailbox.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + mailbox.slice(1)}</h3>`;

  // Fetch all emails
  fetch('/emails/' + mailbox)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(emails => {

      // Loop through all emails
      emails.forEach(email => {

        // Create elements and set the html content
        const sender = document.createElement('p');
        sender.innerHTML = `<strong>From:</strong> ${email.sender}`;

        const subject = document.createElement('p');
        subject.innerHTML = `<strong>Subject:</strong> ${email.subject}`;

        const timestamp = document.createElement('p');
        timestamp.innerHTML = email.timestamp;

        const body = document.createElement('p');
        body.innerHTML = email.body;

        const recipient = document.createElement('p');
        recipient.innerHTML = `<strong>To:</strong> ${email.recipients}`;

        // Create archive button
        const archive = document.createElement('button');
        archive.className = "btn btn-light"

        // Check if email is arquived or not, set the inner html for the button and change status if clicked.
        if (email.archived === true) {
          archive.innerHTML = "Unarchive"

          archive.addEventListener('click', function () {
            fetch('/emails/' + email.id, {
              method: 'PUT',
              body: JSON.stringify(
                { archived: false })
            })
            load_mailbox('inbox')
          });
        }

        else {
          archive.innerHTML = "Archive"

          archive.addEventListener('click', function () {
            fetch('/emails/' + email.id, {
              method: 'PUT',
              body: JSON.stringify(
                { archived: true })
            })
            load_mailbox('inbox')
          });
        }

        // Create main div to hold all elements in the DOM
        const element = document.createElement('div');
        element.className = "div_email_view";

        // Append elements fetch function returned.
        element.appendChild(sender);
        element.appendChild(subject);
        element.appendChild(timestamp);

        // Redirect to email page if div is clicked
        element.addEventListener('click', function () {

          // Hide other divs and show email page one.
          document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'none';
          document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'none';
          document.querySelector('#emails-page').style.display = 'flex';

          // Create reply button
          const reply = document.createElement('button');
          reply.innerHTML = "Reply Email"
          reply.className = "btn btn-light"

          // If reply is clicked, redirect to form in order to compose another email
          reply.addEventListener('click', function () {
            compose_email();
            // Hide other divs
            document.querySelector('#emails-page').style.display = 'none';

            // Pre-fill form inputs with original email content
            document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value = `${email.sender}`;
            if (email.subject.includes("Re:")) {
              document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value = `${email.subject}`;
            }
            else {
              document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value = `Re: ${email.subject}`;
            }
            document.querySelector('#compose-body').placeholder = `On ${email.timestamp}, ${email.sender} wrote: ${email.body}`;
          })

          // Fetch email that was clicked and and display its content
          fetch('/emails/' + email.id)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(() => {
              // Append all info related to that email
              email_page = document.querySelector("#emails-page")
              email_page.appendChild(sender);
              email_page.appendChild(recipient);
              email_page.appendChild(subject);
              email_page.appendChild(body);
              email_page.appendChild(timestamp);

              // Get user email who's logged in
              let user = localStorage.getItem('user')
              // Append archive and reply buttons
              if (user !== email.sender) {
                email_page.appendChild(archive);
              }
              email_page.appendChild(reply);

              // Set the "read" property to true if user has clicked on it to open.
              if (email.read === false) {
                fetch('/emails/' + email.id, {
                  method: 'PUT',
                  body: JSON.stringify({
                    read: true
                  })
                })
              }
            })
        });

        // Append elements to inbox page
        document.querySelector('#emails-view').append(element);
        if (email.read === false) {
          element.style.background = "#FAFAFA";
        }
        else {
          element.style.background = "#E6E6E6";
        }
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: It appears your event listeners for the archive click are calling fetch and load_mailbox, but fetch is an asynchronous method. If you want load_mailbox to fire after the fetch request resolves, you must add an `await` or a `.then` to your fetch statement.